# How a Camel route can call another route running in a different Camel context

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

Is it possible that a camel route can call another route in different Camel Context.

For example, I have a camel context contextA with route routeA and another camel context contextB with route routeB. So how can i call routeB from routeA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a route to be shared consuming (from) with the vm: endpoint, and reference it from other routes using the same endpoint name.

1. Split out the integration logic that you want to share into a route and select a VM Component to consume from that.

If your route should handle requests using the same thread as the caller, choose direct-vm:, otherwise if you want the exchange to be processed asynchronously by a different thread, choose vm:. 
 Give the endpoint a name that will be unique across the JVM.

In the XML DSL, this is written as follows:

```
<route>
<from uri="vm:logMessageToBackendSystem"/> <to uri="..."/>
</route>
```

In the Java DSL, you express the same thing as:

```
from("vm:logMessageToBackendSystem").to(...);
```

2. Invoke the shared route from within the top-level route that needs to make use of this logic by using the same URI pre x.

In the XML DSL, write the following:

```
<route>
    <from uri="..."/>
    <to uri="vm:logMessageToBackendSystem"/>
</route>
```

In the Java DSL, this is written as:

```
from(...).to("vm:logMessageToBackendSystem");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vm component to send exchanges across CamelContext instances. 
http://camel.apache.org/vm.html

Comment: or direct-vm since Camel 2.10  http://camel.apache.org/direct-vm.html  there is only one specific thing: if you use POJO payload in Camel - those POJO classes must be loaded by the same ClassLoader